# webscraping google maps with python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have done a script that you search the location and a keyword, and extract name and address of all results from google maps, i want to save the phone number and the website too but i have no idea how to do it, i tried with XPATH, CSS  Selector and class name, but it doesn't work because the order of infos changes if something is missing.
I tried to do it checking if the icon is displayed but i don't know how to do it well, i am new in this kind of things

```
    try:
        icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[9]/div[6]/a/div[1]/div[1]/div/img")
        website = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[5]/a").get_attribute("href")

    except NoSuchElementException:
        website = "Not found"
    
    
    try:
        icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[6]/button/div[1]/div[1]/div/img")
        phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[6]/button/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        
    except NoSuchElementException:
        phone = "Not found"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
try:
    popup_with_infos = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Hu9e2e")
    icon = popup_with_infos.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img[contains(@src, 'public_gm_blue_24dp.png')]")
    website = icon.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//ancestor::a").get_attribute("href")

except NoSuchElementException:
    website = "Not found"


try:
    popup_with_infos = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Hu9e2e")
    icon = popup_with_infos.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img[contains(@src, 'phone_gm_blue_24dp.png')]")
    phone = icon.find_element(By.XPATH, "./../../..").get_attribute("innerText")

except NoSuchElementException:
    phone = "Not found"
```